# Listing Google Calendar ACLs using Calendar.Acl.list in Apps Script results in error "Execution failed: Not Found"

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

Trying to list and update the Google calendar ACLs using the code below in Google Apps script interface (script.google.com). I have enabled The Calendar API on the GSuite account and can see the API being hit (with 404s and 403s) in the developer console.

The calendarId listed in the code below is fake but, the one I am using does exist and works fine in the developer portal using the *Try this API* form.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/list

I assume I have the adequate authorization because I am logged in using the the same GSuite account on the developer portal and app scripts interface.

Are there any restrictions on the Google Apps Script environment or OAuth authorization that would prohibit this code from running only in Apps Script?

```
function test()
{
    var calendar_acl_list;
    calendar_acl_list = Calendar.Acl.list({calendarId: 'hannibal@domain.com'});
Logger.log('%s', calendars_acl_list);


}
```

It is possible that my simple code is not correct but, the error does not give enough information to troubleshoot. This is the error displayed in the *View>Execution Transcript* menu within Apps Script interface.

```
[17-09-26 14:13:31:492 PDT] Execution failed: Not Found (line 32, file "Code") [0.066 seconds total runtime]
```

Even though the code above is not working. The code below is:

```
function test2()
{
var calendars;
calendars = Calendar.CalendarList.list({maxResults: 100});
Logger.log('%s', calendars);
}
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of OAuth library for this? I don't think it handles this for you entirely automatically; you still probably have to grant your script scopes. See "making requests to services with OAuth" here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external

Comment: I'm writing an apps script on https://script.google.com/. It prompts for OAuth access approval before it executes AFAIK.

Comment: These are the scopes assigned to the related Google Spreadsheet:

Google Calendar
Manage your calendars

Google Services
View users on your domain

Answer (score 1):

The proper usage of the *Calendar.Acl.list* method is:

```
calendarId = 'whatever@gmail.com'    
calendars_acl_list = Calendar.Acl.list(calendarId);
Logger.log('%s', calendars_acl_list);
```