# How to list all emails a Google calendar was shared with?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I would like to get all emails a google Calendar was shared with.

[image]

It seems to me that [Calendar.CalendarList.list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar#listing_calendars) will not give me required info

```
/**
* Lists the calendars shown in the user's calendar list.
*/  
function listCalendars() {
  var calendars;
  var pageToken;
  do {
    calendars = Calendar.CalendarList.list({
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    if (calendars.items && calendars.items.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < calendars.items.length; i++) {
        var calendar = calendars.items[i];
        Logger.log('%s (ID: %s)', calendar.summary, calendar.id);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No calendars found.');
    }
    pageToken = calendars.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

[Calendar.Acl.get(calId, "user:"+user)](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/acl/get) looks promising but I do not know how go get the info I want. Someone could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion

Perhaps you can try this sample script below that was derived from this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436097/listing-google-calendar-acls-using-calendar-acl-list-in-apps-script-results-in-e).

### Sample Script

```
function aclTest(){
  calendarId = 'Calendar_ID';   
  calendars_acl_list = Calendar.Acl.list(calendarId);
  for (var i = 0; i < calendars_acl_list.items.length; i++) {
    var info = calendars_acl_list.items[i];
    if(info.role != "owner" && !info.id.includes("domain")){
      Logger.log(info.id);
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Test:

- Sample Test Calendar

> [image]

- Apps Script result:

> [image]